# Why isn't Spring running my tasks Scheduled in TaskScheduler class?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have the answer to this and will post it. I'm posting this in case this will help someone else in the future.

I had a simple bean class containing two methods with `@Scheduled` annotation. It was working fine, then I renamed the class to `TaskScheduler` after which spring stopped executing the methods.

The class is annotated with `@Component` and `@EnableScheduling`.

Answer (score 1):

The cause was renaming my bean to `TaskScheduler`, which was overridden by spring's `taksScheduler` bean that is part of the scheduling framework.

The fix is to name it something else.

Note that if you enable DEBUG-level logging for `org.springframework`, you will see something like the following:

```
severity="DEBUG" threadname="main" class="o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory" message="Overriding bean definition for bean 'taskScheduler' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.vue.configserver.tasks.TaskScheduler]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\blah\Git\Pearson_VUE_VTS_Services\configserver\Core\build\classes\java\main\com\vue\configserver\tasks\TaskScheduler.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskScheduler; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.class]]" traceId="" spanId="" parentSpanId="" exportable=""
```

(Also note that I had the `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` property set to `true`.)